# jQuery addClass() does not appear to add the CSS class

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I'm horrible at jQuery, just starting to learn. I have a menu structure that's in a .NET master page, in each content page that uses the master page I want to apply a different CSS class to an item in a that UL masterpage list.

```
<section id="navigation">
  <nav id="nav-wrap">
      <ul id="topnav" class="sf-menu">
         <li><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="About.aspx">About</a></li>
         <li class="current"><a href="Purchase.aspx">Buy Now</a></li>
         <li><a href="ContactUs.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul><!-- topnav -->
    </nav><!-- nav -->  
  <div class="clear">
</div>
```

My block I'm calling with jQuery:

```
<section id="navigation">
  <nav id="nav-wrap">
      <ul id="topnav" class="sf-menu">
         <li><a href="Default.aspx" id="homelink" title="Home">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="About.aspx" id="aboutlink" title="About">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="Purchase.aspx" id="buynowlink" title="Buy Now"><span>Buy Now</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="ContactUs.aspx" id="contactuslink" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul><!-- topnav -->
    </nav><!-- nav -->  
  <div class="clear">
</div>
```

When I write the HTML this way, nav element "Buy Now" appears yellow. But this is a master page, so I want to do this with jQuery, so it's not hardcoded in the masterpage.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#buynowlink').addClass('current');
        $('#pagetitle').html('Purchase');
    });
 </script>
```

That jQuery code doesn't appear to apply the CSS or maybe there's something else going wrong? The line below that sets the H1 title for the page works, so I don't think it's an issue of being a page beneath the master page.

What's weird if I do this: it works, so I must have some sort of CSS issue I don't get.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#buynowlink').addClass('current');
        $('#pagetitle').html('Purchase');
        $('#buynowlink').css("color", "yellow");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: And there *is* an element with the ID `buynowlink`?

Comment: Sorry I structured it poorly to begin with, edits above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID is on the `a`, but you want to add the class on the `li`, its parent.

Therefore, you want `$('#buynowlink').parent().addClass('current');`

In cases like this, developer tool such as are built into all mainstream browsers now can show you the current state of the DOM, so that you would inspect the Buy Now link and see that the class had been attached to the anchor rather than the list item.

Answer (score 1):

In a real world I'd suggest to read the URL of the current page and assign a `current` class to the desired link:

```
var pageName = $(location).attr('href').split('/').pop(); // Purchase.aspx


if(pageName===''){
    $('#topnav a[href="Default.aspx"]').addClass('current');
}else{
    $('#topnav a[href="'+pageName+'"]').addClass('current');
}
```

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I don't see any "server" tag

Comment: He says he's using .NET, though. The server *is* the correct place to do it.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I perfectly agree. Should be piece of cake

Answer (score 0):

try this

add `id=BuyNow` in `<li>` element.

```
<section id="navigation">
  <nav id="nav-wrap">
      <ul id="topnav" class="sf-menu">
         <li><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="About.aspx">About</a></li>
         <li id="BuyNow"><a href="Purchase.aspx">Buy Now</a></li>
         <li><a href="ContactUs.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul><!-- topnav -->
    </nav><!-- nav -->  
  <div class="clear">
</div


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#BuyNow').addClass('current');

    });
 </script>
```

Comment: but... it already HAS the class... what are you trying to suggest actually here?

Comment: Sorry I wrote this poorly. I originally had it with the class hard coded..  but move that to a master page, see above I edited it, and removed the li class attribute. There are no hardcoded classes, and I'm trying to get jQuery to add it.

Comment: hi John Batdorf thats my mistake.I didn't notice that. Now I edited